# How to apply 0.0e+000 decimal format?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to have this output: `7.1e+438 from colony 4`
see the input and output in the link

The output is 7.1e+438:
[image]

So I used `toLowerCase()` to get `0.0e000` format without the `+` sign and the numeric values is wrong.

See the code below:

```
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("0.0E000");
System.out.printf(s.toLowerCase() +" from colony %d\n", tempColo);
```

My question here, is there any thing that will give me `0.0e+000` format?

Comment: what is `s` here? What value does it have?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `DecimalFormat` in the code you posted.

Comment: That is right, Is there something I can use to have the format 0.0e+000 ?

Comment: 'An alternative method for `toLowerCase()`' has nothing whatsoever to do with your question. Please fix your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printf function has a whole bunch of different formats. The %e format is what you want to use here.

```
System.out.printf("%1.1e from colony %d\n", d, tempColo);
```

The java API explains all the formats in great detail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I can use to have the format 0.0e+000 ?

As per my understanding you want `E` in lower case along with `+` sign

Simply use `String.replaceAll(regexPattern)` to append `+` if `e` is followed by any digit and use `String.replace()` instead of `String.toLowerCase()` in this case.

```
"7.1E438".replace('E','e').replaceAll("(?<=e)(?=\\d)", "+")  // 7.1e+438
```

[Regex Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR5iA8/1) that uses [*Lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)